# Automata: 1=2, 2= 26, 3=1054, 4=5768, 5 =139314069504, 6 = ???

Tags: sequences-and-series, automata

I am in my own Automaton (finite-state deterministic automata) research, so i have four sets of automata.
2 states automata,
3 states,
4 states and
5 states.

Input alphabet $\{0,1\}$

so...
the amount of automata for each set of states is:

$$       2^n  n^{2n}$$

```
   where: 2= number of state-transition function(depend on intput alphabet)
          n= number of states.
```

for example for 3 states:

$$    2^3 \cdot 3^{2\cdot3} = 5832 $$

by some method(computational) i get two type of automaton,
then i get the next results:

$$\begin{array}{r|rrr}
\text{states} & \text{amount of combinations*} & \text{amount of Type $B$} &  \text{amount of Type $A$**} \\ \hline
      1  &               2          &            0        &             2\\
      2  &              64          &           38        &            26\\
      3  &             5\;832        &          4\;778      &           1\;054\\
      4  &           1\;048\;576      &         991\;508     &          57\;068\\
      5  &          312\;500\;000     &       308\;737\;626   &         3\;762 374\\
      6  &         139\;314\;069\;504  &            ?        &             ?
\end{array}
$$

*Note that: amount type B + amount type A = amount of combinations per state,

** with type B and A, i mean: Isomorphic Automaton and Not Isomorphic Automaton

Isomorphic and Not Isomorphic sample:

if We have 5 automata that they are Isomorphic among them, 1 of them go to the subset of Not Isomorphic, and the another 4 to the subset of Isomorphic.

My question is if, can you help me to get the formula/way to calculate the amount of Type A or Type B, depending  by the states number?

and i am looking for the 6 states results

must be a way to know

i am pretty sure that we could get it with just a modification of this:

$$    2^n  n^{2n}$$
I have tried with Newton's method(numeric method, matrices) but didnt work(better say, I didnt get it).

Comment: How do you define your Type A and Type B automata?

Comment: It doesn't help in this case, but one should always see if the sequence of numbers is listed in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (oeis.org).

Comment: i looked at oeis.org without results, but thank you.

Comment: well... how to define the type is a little complicated, but with type A and B, i mean: Isomorphic Automaton and Not Isomorphic Automaton

Comment: I have no idea what's an Isomorphic automaton or a Not Automorphic automaton. Are you counting isomorphism classes of automata ?

Comment: two automata are Isomorphic if for any input string they do the same.

Comment: Yes, I know when one automaton is isomorphic to another automaton. That doesn't say what's an "Isomorphic" automaton. That's like talking about "Greater than" integers.

Comment: ok, i already edited the quiestion to explain it.

Comment: So, the numbers under "Type A" give the number of equivalence classes of automata?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk, numbers under "Type A" give the number of diferent Automata you can get(lets say you have 100 autoamta, but only 20 of them are diferent, each one of the other 80 is equal to one in the 20), but what the number means doesnt matter, what matters is how to get that number

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly an answer, but maybe this observation may help you. For amount of type A you can write

$$26=2^5-2^2-2^1$$
$$1054=2^{11}-2^9-2^8-2^7-2^6-2^5-2^1$$
$$57068=2^{16}-2^{13}-2^8-2^4-2^2$$
$$3762374=2^{22}-2^{18}-2^{17}-2^{15}-2^{12}-2^{10}-2^9-2^8-2^5-2^4-2^3-2^1$$

and I suspect that for the type B you can find something similar.

Comment: thank you, nice observation, but it does not seem to keep a pattern

Answer (score 0):

my observation is:

1 : 2     = 2^1

2 : 26    = 2^1 + 2^3 + 2^4

3 : 1054  = 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^10

4 : 57068 = 2^2 + 2^3 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^9 + 2^10 + 2^11 + 2^12 + 2^14 + 2^15

and this does not follow any pattern